# Is this function analytic at the origin?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(x) = \frac{x \cos x }{\sin x } $. Claim is that $f$ is analytic at $x=0$.

I dont think so. But, if wet define $f(0)= 1$ then it becomes analytic since

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 1 \cdot \cos 0  = 1 $$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically we should say there is a removable singularity at $z = 0$, meaning that $f$ can be *extended* to a function which is analytic at $z = 0$, as you mention. This is the precise way of saying things, but I have heard people refer to functions with removable singularities as themselves being analytic. My understanding is that this is one of those things that people say because everyone understands what is really meant and it's often not worth the trouble to make the distinction. This is because even though $f$ is not defined at $z = 0$ it does have a power series expansion around zero.

Also, in general if a function $f$ is analytic in some open set $\Omega \subset\mathbb{C}$ except for some $z_0 \in \Omega$, and if $f$ is bounded in $\Omega - \{z_0\}$ then $f$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$. This is [Riemann's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity) of removable singularities.